# 'Strange' variable assignment behavior inside JQuery on("click") function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to both javascript and jquery, and I'm having a small problem. It is happening with both the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, so I don't think it's a browser issue.

Relevant code is here (this is a self-invoking function inside script tags on the HTML page).

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var submitbutton = $('#submitcommand'),
        textinput = $('#textinput'),
        userinput = textinput.val();

    submitbutton.on('click', function() {
        alert("textinput is " + textinput.val());   // => works
        alert("userinput is " + userinput);     // => undefined

    });
}());
```

The first call to alert() works just fine, using 'textinput.val()'. The second call to alert() doesn't return any visible text, because 'userinput' is evaluating to 'undefined'.

I've tried going into the Firebug Console and pasting the four statements (the two assignments and the two calls to alert()) in, one after the other. That works, and gets me the result I expect.

So the question is: what changes about the 'userinput' variable inside the on('click') function? What am I not seeing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Userinput is initialized when the function is first run, is there a value in the field at that point? Is there even a field? We don't know when the function is being run.

Comment: Yep, move the userinput = line into the command button function, both values are nothing until you click that button, the textinput one works because it is getting that value after the button click.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The first answer I got to this was right (although the answer has been removed now?)! The problem was that the function wasn't inside a document ready handler. Because the answer that solved it was removed, I'm putting the fixed code in the question. The script tag that this code sits in is just before the </body> tag.

Comment: I added some notes to my answer for your updated question regarding the event handler hook.

Comment: Note that IF you had placed the script AFTER the elements here, it would have worked to get the "initial" value of the element, which, falling after your script tag was "undefined" during the initial execution - still not the actual current value during the submit event, but not "undefined" at least.  The "document ready" event runs after that initial parse/execution, so it exists at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the function is self invoking, the variable will be set at page load. It is not reassessed every time the button is clicked. During page load you will probably find that:

1. The input is emtpy
2. The input is lower down the page than the script (More probable I think)

So at the time of setting there is no value. You probably want to make the variable scoped to the button click:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var submitbutton = $('#submitcommand'),
        textinput = $('#textinput')

    submitbutton.on('click', function() {
        var userinput = textinput.val();

        alert("textinput is " + textinput.val());   // => works
        alert("userinput is " + userinput);     // => undefined

    });
}());
```

Also, you will want to make sure the script block is at the bottom of the page, as then all the UI elements will be loaded in the browser when the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Your value is undefined inside the handler.

You should perhaps use it this way:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var submitbutton = $('#submitcommand'),
        textinput = $('#textinput')
        userinput = textinput.val();
    submitbutton.on('click', function() {
        userinput = textinput.val();// sets the value in the handler
        alert("textinput is " + textinput.val()); 
        alert("userinput is " + userinput); 
    });
}());
```

working example:http://jsfiddle.net/avCay/

Note that this works this way due to the scope of the variable and the "reset" of the values inside the event handler.  The first pass parses the script, the second executes it, and the subsequent event handler fires on the click event of the submitbutton element, setting the value at that point during that event.

EDIT: NOTE: regarding the jQuery read/load wrap (as in my example fiddle) if you wish to NOT have that, you can do:
 `$('#submitcommand').on('click', function() {` 
instead of the variable and jQuery will properly hook the event handler to the element.

EDIT2: or perhaps this will provide more insight here.  If you do:

You will still need to re-access the variable however if you wish to have the "current" value of the input, not that in the "undefined" state during the initial execution due to the parse/execute cycle of the Javascript.  **The "re-access" of the .val(); vs the value during the initial script execution is the key to that "undefined" value. and setting it "inside" the handler gets the current value.**

Answer (score 0):

When

```
var userinput = textinput.val()
```

is evaluated:

1. `textinput` may not exist yet - you must be either in a `document.ready()` handler or the `<script>` block must be after `#textinput` in the DOM.
2. if it *does* exist, `userinput` gets its *current* value, not any future value it may happen to have.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value of `#textinput` is empty on page load (unless you set the value to something when the page loads). So the stored value in `userinput` is empty. When you read the value from `textinput` inside the event handler, it looks up the value of the input-field.

Makes sense? :)